# Autofac Auto Registering Services and ProxyServices

Tags: c#, autofac

Our app has both services and proxy services, and they both inherit from the same interface.

```
public class UserService : IUserService {}

public class UserProxyService : IUserService {}
```

Within our app, we need to be able to work with both of them independently. The way we're doing that is we inject the Interface if we're using the Service, and we inject the concrete Proxy if we're using the ProxyService.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IUserService userService, UserProxyService userProxyService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _userProxyService = userProxyService;
    }
}
```

The question comes when I try to Auto Register my services

```
_containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly)
                 .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                 .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The above obviously doesn't work. I was hoping that `Except` would allow something along the lines of

```
_containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembly)
                 .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                 .Except(x => x.Name.EndsWith("ProxyService"))
                 .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

but alas, it does not.

Is there way to auto register classes with the above corner case?

Note: the Services and the ProxyServices are in separate namespaces, and the Interface is in the same namespace as the Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
.Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")  && !t.Name.EndsWith("ProxyService"))
.AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: ah yes, I suppose the expression visitor should be able to handle that... so easy.